# Java date string parse creates difference of timezone

Tags: java, parsing, date, datetime

I am bit frustrated by this.

I have a String `"2015-02-18T23:44:59"` which represents time in GMT format.

I want to parse this date into date object.

```
String dateStr = "2015-02-18T23:44:59";
Date date = DateUtils.parseDate(dateStr, new String[]{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"});
System.out.println(dateStr + " \t" + date.toString());
```

This outputs :

```
2015-02-18T23:44:59     Thu Feb 19 05:14:59 IST 2015
```

As you can see latter time has time zone IST but my original time was GMT.
I don't think there is any parse function which takes current date's time zone.

One way to answer is this question is that :

```
date.setTime(date.getTime() + ( date.getTimezoneOffset()  * 60 * 1000));
System.out.println("\t"  + date.toString());
```

This outputs:

```
Wed Feb 18 23:44:59 IST 2015
```

Which seems correct time (but incorrect time zone). Additionally, `getTimezoneOffset()` is deprecated.

Can anyone suggest me a better way to deal with String dates considering time zones.

Comment: You're simply printing the `toString()` of a `java.util.Date`, which simply represents a millisecond offset from the datum time.  A `Date` has no knowledge of specific timezones, so `Date.toString()` always converts it using the local zone.

Comment: Thanks @IanRoberts for your input. I'm well aware of that fact.

I'll bit explain in detail for you. The string date is in UTC time zone. After converting that time into date, it should make appropriate changes in the time zone. So correct output would be `Thu Feb 19 05:14:59 IST 2015`. You can see this is the correct output. Though here timezone is IST, time is accordingly adjusted. That's what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a date format:

```
SimpleDateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = utcFormat.parse("2015-02-18T23:44:59");
```